# Navigate to second tab after refreshing content in jQuery

Tags: jquery, tabs

How to select a jQuery tab after reloading page to get the updated content?

I have multiple tabs using jQuery. For e.g. 2nd tab content is updated from external page now this tab still shows old content.

I hit refresh but it always go to 1st tab. I would like to go to 2nd tab if I'm currently in 2nd tab.

Tried:

```
location.reload(true);
window.navigate ("<?php echo $labURL; ?>" + "<?php echo $webDir; ?>" + "/" + "<?php echo $getLab; ?>" + "/#tabs-" + $activeTab);
```

It refreshes content using reload but it doesn't navigate automatically to 2nd tab.

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle and share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer after fumbling a lot:

window.location.href = "" + "" + "/" + "" + "/#tabs-" + $activeTab;
                location.reload(true);

First change the URL using href and then navigate, i was actually doing reverse of it.